# Testing GC Pressure in Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, load-testing, performance-testing

I'm running a load-test in Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate.  The load test executes only a single MsTest unit test repeatedly.

I'd like to know how much pressure on the GC my code is creating.  I can't figure how to do this.

I started by looking for memory-related counters in the default list provided by the load-test.  By default a load-test run will make available counters in the following categories:

- Overall
- <Scenario Name>
- Computers
- Errors

The "Computers" option expands to provide several options, one of which is "Memory."  When I expand "Memory", I don't see anything that pertains to the GC.

So now it is time to add additional counters to the default list.

To do this, I open the load-test definition and go to the "Counter Sets" and select "Add Custom Counter Set."  I then "Add Counters" and select ".NET CLR Memory".  I request "all counters" and "all instances".

When I then run the load-test, I don't see any way to have these new counters reported or to show-up in a graph.  The "Counters Pane" unfortunately shows the same list of choices that I started with.  The executing load test doesn't show any sign of using or monitoring the newly added counters.

What am I missing?

### Update

Based on input from John O., I added the ".NET CLR Memory" counter to the "Agent" counter set.  This did indeed allow the new counter to be accessible in the "Counter" pane and visible in the graphs.  However, when I selected ".NET CLR Memory", I also had the option of what "instances" the counter would cover.  I don't know which of these to select:

- *Global*
- BuildNotification
- deven
- devenv #1
- devenv #2
- MSBuild
- MSBuild #1
- MSBuild #2
- SCNotification
- TfsComProviderSvr
- TfsComProviderSvr #1
- vstest.discoveryengine.x86

The multiple instances above, such as devenv #1 and devenv #2 apparently represent the three instances of Visual Studio I currently have open on my desktop.  But this still doesn't tell me which item above I should select in order for the counter to "look" only at my load-test code-under-test.  I have selected the "all instances" radio button, but I'd prefer to know what precisely I should be selecting.

Comment: You can give the scenario a startup delay and the load test a cool down period. Then you should see a period at the start and finish when the tests are not running. Examine all the counters listed to see which change while the test is actually running.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're adding a whole new counter set. No counters in the counter set will appear in the load test results unless the set is mapped in the 'Run Settings' part of the load-test definition.

What you need to do is add the additional counters to one of the existing counter sets.

In the load-test definition right click on the 'Agent' counter set (I'm assuming you want to measure the memory on the agent machines executing the tests) and select 'Add Counter'. From here do what you did before.

Now, since the 'Agent' counter set should already be mapped in the 'Run Settings', you should see the counter available for graphing next time you run the test.

**Update**

Since you want to add the memory counter to a new machine, your original steps in your question were the right way to go. You just need to then map the new counter set to whatever machine you want to measure.

1. Open load-test definition, go to 'Counter Sets' and select 'Add Custom Counter'.
2. Select '.NET CLR Memory' and save the new counter set
3. Now go to the 'Run Settings' section of the load-test definition. Right click 'Counter Set Mappings' and select 'Manage Counter Sets...'
4. A new dialogue window will appear. Click on the 'Add Computer' button.
5. Put in the machine name of the box on which you want to measure the GC pressure. Click on the [+] next to the machine.
6. A bunch of nodes should appear showing the counter sets you can map too the machine. You should see the counter set you created - check it and click on 'OK'
7. Now the load-test definition should display your machine on which you're measuring GC in the 'Counter Set Mappings' section.

Comment: You are correct that adding the .NET CLR Memory counter to the agent made it available (under "Computers").  However, I assume there is a separation between agents and my code-under-test.  I want to measure the GC pressure of my code-under-test, not the agents.  I assume the agents can or do run in a separate process.   Any info on this?

Comment: There should definitely be a separation between your code-under-test and the agents - they should be on entirely different machines. See the update in my answer for steps to add the counter set to the machine running your code-under-test.

Answer (score 0):

Collecting data and graphing it are two separate activities.

Open the test results in Visual Studio and view the graphs that are available. Use the context (right-click) menu of one of the graphs and select **Add graph**. In the counters pane select a counter you want graphed and then either drag it onto the new graph or use its context menu and select **Show counters on graph**.

Individual counters can be added to a graph. Normally one level above the individual counters in the tree can be added, but not higher levels. Extra counters can also be added to some of the standard graphs.

New graphs can also be added while a test is running.

Comment: What you have described is what I'm trying to do...but the "counters pane" does not show the new "custom" counters I added to the load-test definition.  I can't drag in a new counter from the pane, if it is not being shown in the pane.